# Как запустить другой скрипт node js?

Tags: node.js

Как можно запустить сторонний файл, передать параметры и дождаться его завершения, получив результат?

---

Вот код

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const test = spawn('/data/upload/test.js',  ['-lh', '/usr']);

test.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

test.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

test.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

выводит

> { [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall:
>   'spawn' } Exception while invoking method 'renderPDF' Error: spawn
>   EACCES
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)

Comment: [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили [тщательный поиск ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=child_process+%5Bnode.js%5D). Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Когда пробую spawn, то выводятся ошибки при его запуске.

Comment: у тебя синтаксическая ошибка в test.js

Comment: А сейчас возникает ошибка прав 
Error: spawn EACCES

Из-за чего это?

Comment: Смотри описания ошибок в [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors). Скорее всего, у тебя пермиссии на запускаемый файл (или на каталожки по пути к нему) не пересекаются с правами пользователя от имени которого запущен процесс.

Comment: А эта команда spawn, она использует node_modules которые лежат в папке в которой запускается файл или этот файл будет использовать модули которые использует родительский файл?

Comment: "в которой запускается файл"